# UWP Launcher. How to import Laucher class

Tags: uwp

I've found Launcher class to use in UWP:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt784669.aspx
However, i failed to import Launcher class in UWP. The class could not be found.
System.Windows.Launcher.

My imports:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
```

Comment: Your question might seem too broad for some users - please add any config details you find relevant, and include a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if possible.

Comment: you can refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.System.Launcher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is Windows.System.Launcher, not System.Windows.Launcher.

In case you are trying to use it from a non-UWP app, also make sure you reference Windows.winmd (in UWP this is automatically referenced).

Comment: What is the error? Are you actually building a UWP app, or a WPF app? If the latter make sure you add a reference to Windows.winmd as pointed out.

Comment: i don't know what i'm building. store app i would like. using Microsoft Blend

Comment: If you start with File->New->Project->Windows Universal->Blank App, does Windows.System.Launcher work for you? That's how you create a store app (UWP). You can use Blend to develop it.

Comment: i've might have did it